# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Display.VirtualDisplay'

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, virtual-functions

What to do with this error this code is for screen recorder which is giving error after the toggle button is clicked means it say application closed without doing any furthur operation but app launches initially very well But the problem ocurs when clicked the button

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 11;
private static final int MEDIA_CODE = 12;
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTAIONS = new SparseIntArray();

private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
private MediaProjection mediaProjection;
private VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

private MediaProjectionCallback mediaProjectionCallback;

private int mScreenDensity;
private static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1280;
static
{
    ORIENTAIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTAIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTAIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTAIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private ToggleButton btnToggle;
private VideoView videoView;
private String videoUri = "";
private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnToggle = findViewById(R.id.btnToggle);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

    btnToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
             + ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO))
                {
                    btnToggle.setChecked(false);
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Permissions", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CODE);
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toggleScreenShare(v);
            }
        }
    });


}

private void toggleScreenShare(View v) {
    if (((ToggleButton)v).isChecked())
    {
        initRecorder();
        screenRecord();
    }
    else
    {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        stopRecordScreen();

        //Video View
        videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUri));
        videoView.start();
    }
}

private void screenRecord() {
    if (mediaRecorder == null)
    {
        startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), MEDIA_CODE);
        return;
    }
    virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
    mediaRecorder.start();
}

private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {

    return mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);

}

private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

        videoUri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                + new StringBuilder("/Video_Screen").append(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh_mm_ss")
        .format(new Date())).append(".mp4").toString();

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoUri);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH,DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512*1000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTAIONS.get(rotation + 90);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unknown error..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
        if (requestCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnToggle.setChecked(false);
            return;
        }

        mediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mediaProjection.registerCallback(mediaProjectionCallback, null);
       virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mediaRecorder.start();

}

private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (btnToggle.isChecked())
        {
            btnToggle.setChecked(false);
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.reset();

        }

        mediaProjection = null;
        stopRecordScreen();
        super.onStop();
    }

}
private void stopRecordScreen() {

    if (virtualDisplay == null)
        return;
    virtualDisplay.release();
    destroyMediaProjection();
}

private void destroyMediaProjection() {
    if (mediaProjection != null)
    {
        mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mediaProjectionCallback);
        mediaProjection.stop();
        mediaProjection = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                toggleScreenShare(btnToggle);
            }
            else
            {

                btnToggle.setChecked(false);
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Permissions", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("ENABLE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUEST_CODE);
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

}

Below is Log_cat

````
    Process: com.aman.screenrecorderapp, PID: 32086
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay android.media.projection.MediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String, int, int, int, int, android.view.Surface, android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay$Callback, android.os.Handler)' on a null object reference
        at com.aman.screenrecorderapp.MainActivity.createVirtualDisplay(MainActivity.java:146)
        at com.aman.screenrecorderapp.MainActivity.screenRecord(MainActivity.java:140)
        at com.aman.screenrecorderapp.MainActivity.toggleScreenShare(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.aman.screenrecorderapp.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:36)
        at com.aman.screenrecorderapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:107)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4799)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20042)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)```
````

Comment: Your mediaprojection is null. Put breakpoints in your code to see why it fails. Start with this line:         mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

Comment: Check this answer for more info [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nothing worked for me please give me ideas regarding codes why it is happening and how it can be solve Thanks...